# Remove Number plus any special character or letter that follows it (from postal address)

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to remove the street numbers from addresses, for example 30 Main Street.

Simple ones work fine:

```
# remove numbers, strip remaining white space at left
re.sub(r'[0-9]+', '', '30 Main Street').lstrip()

'Main Street'
```

However some have letters or commas attached to the number, e.g.

`30B Main Street`
`30b, Main Street`
`30, Main Street'

I am trying to include commas or letters that are attached to the number. It works:

```
re.sub(r'[0-9]+\w\,', '', '30b, Main Street').lstrip()

'Main Street'
```

But now it doesn't work for the original simple address:

```
re.sub(r'[0-9]+\w\,', '', '30 Main Street').lstrip()

'30 Main Street'
```

I have tried adding an 'or' to the regex using `|` as suggested by some tutorials, but now this doesn't detect any letters:

```
re.sub(r'[0-9]+|[0-9]+\w\,', '', '30b, Main Street').lstrip()

'b, Main Street'
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may specify *optional* character class for *letters or commas*:

```
import re

pat = re.compile(r'\b\d+[a-z,]*\s*', re.I)

print(pat.sub('', '30b, Main Street'))   # Main Street
print(pat.sub('', '30 Main Street'))     # Main Street
```

---

- `[a-z,]*` - matches zero or more occurrences of either letter `a-z` or comma `,`
- `\s*` - matches zero or more occurrences of whitespace char `\s` (so you don't need to `.lstrip()` after)

Comment: Thanks, but if I try that with `'10 foobar street'` it doesn't work!

Comment: @SCool, no problem, fixed

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to match comma's or letters attached to the number, you could use optional chars a-zA-Z and match an optional comma:

```
\b[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]*,?\s*
```

**Explanation**

- `\b[0-9]+` Match 1+ digits preceded by a word boundary preventing the digits being part of a larger word
- `[a-zA-Z]*` Match 0+ chars a-zA-Z
- `,?\s*` Match optional comma and 0+ whitespace chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gl9IMB/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/xFvAkG)

```
import re
strings = [
    "30B Main Street",
    "30b, Main Street",
    "30, Main Street",
    "10 foobar street"
    ]
for s in strings:
    print(re.sub(r'\b[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]*,?\s*', '', s))
```

Result

```
Main Street
Main Street
Main Street
foobar street
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest removing the numbers first as though of originally, then have 2nd line of code that would substitute comma with an empty space and finally trim any whitespace. Not the most elegant solution, but pretty straightforward and works (at least in PHP it does). Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not sure if this would work for `10B Main Street`. I would be left with `B Main Street` as I'm only removing the number. I need the letter attached to the number gone too.